# problems with ng-repeat using tabs

Tags: angularjs, uiview, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-tabset

I've been problems when use a link inside tabs, that change the view and replace the tabs as well. The problem only occurs when use ng-repeat in tabs but no with static tabs.

That's the main page:

```
<div  ui-view name="pageContent">
<uib-tabset>
    <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.name}}"  active="tab.active" ng-click="!tab.disable && load(tab.link,tab.id)">
    </uib-tab>
    <!-- <uib-tab heading="Static title">Static content</uib-tab>
    <uib-tab heading="Static title">Static content 2</uib-tab> <!-- when I use the comment code it works. -->
    </uib-tabset>
    <div>
        <a class="btn btn-link" ui-sref="xxxx.yyyyy" role="button">
            {{$storage.aaaa.bbbbb}}
        </a><!-- this view replace the pageContent -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The error is:

> Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'uibTabset', required by directive 'uibTab', can't be found!

Thanks in advance

Comment: it looks like it's a known bug (it seems it hasn't been fixed yet ) : https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3692 I haven't read the whole thread but i think the solution is here

Comment: the error is similar, though not exactly the same but they talk about ng-repeat and ui-view so it looks like the situation is the same. One of the latest answers (13 days ago) says: 

I believe one should not nest the tabs inside a <ui-view> element - the error disappears on the Plunker above when one moves it out, as demonstrated here. If one wants to control display, one can use a simple ng-show/ng-hide or ng-if.

Comment: Very thanks Nam. I'll do that

Comment: let us know if it worked and what you did to fix that

Answer (score 5):

I sorted out. That's the code.

```
 <div class="row top-margin" ng-show=" uiRouterState.current.name !='xxxx'">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <uib-tabset>
         <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.name}}"  active="tab.active" ng-click="!tab.disable && load(tab.link,tab.id)">
         </uib-tab>
     </uib-tabset>
  </div>
</div>
<div  ui-view name="pageContent">      
 <a class="btn btn-link" ui-sref="xxxx" role="button">
     Link 
 </a><!-- this link replace the "pageContent" with view xxxxx  -->
<div>
```

I've created a $scope variable in the controller called $scope.uiRouterState = $state, to store the current state.

Comment: Thanks for posting answer

Answer (score 0):

much cleaner way bellow:

> I am using pug beware of(change) the syntax if you have pure html.

```
 uib-tabset(type="tabs")
 uib-tab(ng-repeat="tabs in tabs track by $index" ng-click="$index = !$index" )
  uib-tab-heading
    span {{ tabs.name }}
    div(ng-if="$index === true")
      span {{ content goes here }}
```